# Whats identifies a 'Unit' in Borland/Embarcadero CBuilder IDE

Tags: c++builder-6, c++builder-2010

I have a number of c++ projects were units were added. After working a while on these projects some of these units change into a .cpp file and a .h file with no connection between the two anymore.

When I click the header file in the "project manager", the .cpp file gets focus in the IDE. I have to right click on the .cpp source and choose "open source/header file" to open the header file. Normal behaviour in a unit is a set of tabs below the source window to choose between source and header.

How can I restore this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.cpp` and `.h` files need to have the same base name, eg `<name>.cpp` and `<name>.h`, for example `Unit1.cpp` and `Unit1.h`.  And the `.h` file needs to have a header guard named `<name>H`, for example `Unit1H`.  Then, the IDE will treat the files (and any associated `<name>.dfm` file) as a single "unit".

Comment: In my case the header guard was not in the <name>H format but <name>_H. Because the filename in my project is an abbreviation in all caps (DSTV.h) I did not want the header guard to be "DSTVH". I have changed that from "DSTV_H" to "DSTVh" now but I consider it a serious flaw in CBuilder that not some characters like underscore are allowed in the guard name..